# How to create Custom option menu class display 5 menu name in one line

Tags: android

I am very new to android application development.I want to know how to create custom option menu class in android so that it is able to display 5 menu name in one Any help will be

greatly appreciated...
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidMenusMyWay.aspx